# Citation call-outs of the form [1,3-7]

Tags: citing, cite-package

How one can get a citation as the one in the title when some references are consecutive, for example: the code

```
\cite{ref1,ref3-ref7}
```

does not work. However, I see this in many papers.

Is there any simple way to do it ?

Say I'm using the following simple code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\cite{a, d,e,f,g,h}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{a} Ref1
\bibitem{b} Ref2
\bibitem{d} Ref3
\bibitem{e} Ref4
\bibitem{f} Ref5
\bibitem{g} Ref6
\bibitem{h} Ref7
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Then `\cite{a, d,e,f,g,h}` gives [1,3,4,5,6,7].

Comment: use package `cite`. Then `\cite{ref1, ref3, ref4, ref5, ref6, ref7}`.

Comment: I want to get it like this [1,3-7] not [1,3,4,5,6,7].

Comment: You don't know the numbering of citation beforehand (assuming that you are using bibtex). You specify explicitly, and then the package (`cite`) will simplify consecutive ones.

Comment: I'm using bibtex but it does not specify it as I stated. They are all listed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: Let me clarify. In the source code, you always cite like `\cite{a, c, d, e, f, g}`. There is no magic command that lets you write `\magiccite{a, c-g}`; even if there are, it has little use given the nature of bibtex. Now, what you see on other people's paper is [1, 3-7], which is an aftereffect of `\usepackage{cite}`. The main purpose of that package is to simply consecutive numbers (3, 4, 5, 6, 7) into range (3-7).

Comment: @Mico Thanks. It's the plain style.

Comment: @Symbol Yeah I understand this, I'm looking for the aftereffect which does not appear in my case.

Comment: It ***should***. But I am not familiar with `plain`. I recommend the standard process: `compile` -> `bibtex` -> `compile` -> `compile`. If that doesn't help, I am useless =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design, the ordering of the entries in the bib file has no meaning. Therefore,

```
\cite{ref1,ref3-ref7}
```

has *no chance whatsoever* of working. In fact, BibTeX will issue a warning that it couldn't find an entry with key `ref3-ref7` in the bib file.

The `cite` package allows multiple arguments in a single `\cite` instruction and performs sorting and compression (unless one instructs it not to do so). If the `cite` package is loaded, then

```
\cite{ref1,ref3,ref4,ref5,ref6,ref7}
```

will indeed generate

```
[1, 3--7]
```

as long as the `ref2` entry is also cited somewhere in the document. (Obviously, for this simple example to work, I must assume that `ref1` through `ref7` will be sorted in that order in the typeset bibliography.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{a,author="A",title="Thoughts",year=3001}
@misc{b,author="B",title="Thoughts",year=3002}
@misc{c,author="C",title="Thoughts",year=3003}
@misc{d,author="D",title="Thoughts",year=3004}
@misc{e,author="E",title="Thoughts",year=3005}
@misc{f,author="F",title="Thoughts",year=3006}
@misc{g,author="G",title="Thoughts",year=3007}
\end{filecontents*}  

\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\cite{b}
\cite{a,c,d,e,f,g}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please see my edit; I'm using a simple code in my case.

Comment: @S.Maths - It's necessary to load the `cite` package to get sorting and compression.